# Database values to array and join with VBscript

Tags: sql, arrays, join, asp-classic, vbscript

The values at the database look like 10000000,10000001,10000002. Now I have the value saved to a string (ID) and I want to assign a new value if its in and do a join so that it would come out as 0a,1a,2b.

```
Dim LineOfText 
Dim i 
Dim aryTextFile(12) 
if ID.contains("10000000") then
aryTextFile(9) = "0a"
end if
if ID.contains("10000002") then
aryTextFile(10) = "1a"
end if
if ID.contains("10000001") then
aryTextFile(11) = "2b"
end if 

LineOfText = String.Join(",", aryTextFile)
```

Trying this it gives me the error
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: '10000001,10000002'

So what am I doing wrong?

After thinking some maybe I'm not making the value into a string right.

```
strSQL = "SELECT ID from table where hdnID like 3696 "
set objRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1
Dim ID
ID = objRec("ID")
```

I have this working in C# but need a vbscript equivalent
The c# code is

```
string[] Otherspace = new string[] { 1a, 2b, 3c };
                string txaNotes = String.Join(", ", Otherspace.Where(q => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LineOfText = join(aryTextFile, ",")
```

Comment: Was on there but I guess it was descriptive enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .Net import to build an Array, then joining it.

Example of how you can achieve this:

```
Dim DataList, ID
ID = "10000000 foo 10000002 bar"
Set DataList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

If instr(ID, "10000000") Then DataList.Add "0a"
If instr(ID, "10000001") Then DataList.Add "1a"
If instr(ID, "10000002") Then DataList.Add "2b"

LineOfText = join(DataList.ToArray, ", ")
' LineOfText will have value "0a, 2b"
```